# Android Email validation is not working

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile

Am validating the email before inserting into database. But am not able to validating. Am not getting any errors.

```
final EditText email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final String Email1 = email.getText().toString().trim();
final String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
public void onClick(View v) {

            if((email.getText().toString().length()==0)) 
            {

                //email.setError( "Please Enter Valid Id" );
                Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this,"Please Enter EmailId", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                return;
               }
            else if(!(isValidEmail(Email1))){
                Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this,"Invalid Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
            return;
            }


    public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    return !TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
        }
```

Comment: which is the email address you try to validate with the given pattern?

Comment: "([\\w\\-]([\\.\\w])+[\\w]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4})";  use this pattern for email.

Comment: my email pattern would be xxxxxxx123@xxx.xxx.xxx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method

```
     public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    return !TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
        }
```

Let me explain you in detail,

```
        final EditText email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final String Email1 = email.getText().toString().trim();
    if(!isValidEmail(Email1 )){
    //INVALID EMAIL ID
    }else{
    //VALID EMAIL ID
    }
```

According to your code update this

```
    final EditText email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final String Email1 = email.getText().toString().trim();

    public void onClick(View v) {

        if((Email1.toString().length()==0)) 
        {

            //email.setError( "Please Enter Valid Id" );
            Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this,"Please Enter EmailId", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            return;
           }
        else if(!isValidEmail(Email1)){
            Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this,"Invalid Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
        return;
        }
        }


public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
return !TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
    }
```

Comment: Am beginner, can you explain more. where to put your code..?

Comment: I didnt find any difference in your code except "}" at the end

Comment: Did you try the code? What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Am not getting any error in logs,
when enter "santhos" in edittext it gives "Invalid Email" as per the code, and when i enter "santhos@xx.xxx.xxx" again it gives "Invalid Email" on my screen and not able to move to next page.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code.

```
public static boolean emailValidation(String emailid) {
        String expression = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(emailid);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method:

```
public static boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
        String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
```

**Sample:**

```
if((email.getText().toString().length()>0){
         if(isValidEmail(email.getText().toString())){
            //Valid email
         }
}
```

Comment: Am getting "Please Valid EmailId" even after trying your code

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Validation {
String pattern = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

public static boolean isValidEmail(EditText editText) {

        String email = editText.getText().toString().trim();
        if (email.matches(pattern)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Call above method where you need to check Validation of email like below.
This will works for me

```
Validation.isValidEmail(yourEmail Edittext);
```

Comment: Android has a utility method to check if email is valid or not.

Comment: That's great you can also use that.